# calling dotnet from .sh file through cron is not working

Tags: .net, linux, amazon-ec2, cron, sh

I have a script file.sh that run a dotnet app "dotnet app.name.dll", its working fine when i call it from the terminal "./file.sh".
I made a cron using "crontab -e" to run this script every day, it call the script "file.sh" but its gave me the error : /home/ec2-user/file.sh: line 3: dotnet: command not found

log file :

```
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_SESSION_ID=423>
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000>
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ec2-user>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ec2-user>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=ec2-user>
/home/ec2-user/file.sh: line 3: dotnet: command not found
```

dotnet is working fine in the terminal or even when i call the file.sh directly

Comment: Can you try giving full path to dotnet in the script? `/full/path/to/dotnet`

Comment: is there a command to give me the dotnet path ?

Comment: Try: `which dotnet`

Comment: dotnet path is : /usr/local/bin/dotnet

Comment: my cron is : #!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/ec2-user/Folder/
dotnet app.name.dll

Comment: Thanx Its work you can post a reply so i can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving full path to `dotnet` in the script? `/full/path/to/dotnet`

Based on your answers to my questions:

```
/usr/local/bin/dotnet
```